# Send empty array from ajax to jersey web server

Tags: java, arrays, ajax, rest, jersey

I try to send array of integers from ajax to jersey web service.

javascript

```
    var myFoods = [];

    // adding items via push

    $.ajax({
        url: "ws/food/" + idParam + "/recomendation",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'foods[]': myFoods,
        async: false,
    });
```

web service

```
@POST
@Path("/{id}/recomendation")
public void updateRecomendations(
        @PathParam("id")
        Long id,

        @FormParam("foods[]")
        List<Long> recomendedFoodIds
        ) {
        ...
    }
```

With non empty arrays this code work good but if myFoods is empty i have error

```
"HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this:

```
@POST
@Path("/{id}/recomendation")
public void updateRecomendations(
        Form form,

        @PathParam("id")
        Long id
        ) {
        List<Long> foods = getFoodIdsFromForm(form);

        ...
    }

private List<Long> getFoodIdsFromForm(Form form) {
    Map parametrsMap = form.asMap();
    final List<Long> foodIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
    if (parametrsMap.get("foods[]") != null) {
        List<String> idsString = (List<String>)parametrsMap.get("foods[]");
        for (String id : idsString) {
            foodIds.add(Long.parseLong(id));
        }
    }

    return foodIds;
}
```